# Android ShowcaseView Usage - Unable to import it to my Project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, showcaseview

I finished my App, and now i want to add a tutorial. I found the ShowcaseView Library and i really want to use it. The Problem is the import of this library.

Iam new to this whole Android/Eclipse thing, and i dont know exactly how this whole importing of libraries work. Since i spend days of researching in the internet for a real noob step by step guide using/importing showcaseview (meaning: download this, select this folder, do this, click here, because of that, etc..), i only found outdated guides and not very detailed and everything is crashing.

What i know:
- I need the showcasview library
- I need the actionbarsherlock library, but i dont know which of the folders in the downloaded .zip is the library-folder.
- I dont know how to import theselibrary und i dont know the dependencies between those libraries and my project

Information to my Project:
- Target Api: 19 
- Min : 11 
- My Project contains appcombat-v7 -libray ??? (what is it used for ?)
- and contains google-api library for ad

I would be glad for a small step by step guide or explanation for all this library import/usage.

thanks everyone, for spending time reading this. (probably its a very dumb question ... :/ )

Comment: Have you downloaded showcaseview library?

Comment: yes, from [here](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Comment: Have you also downloaded actionbarsherlock library? Do you want to import both libraries into your project?

Comment: @GrIsHu Is actionbarsherlock library requiered for using ShowcaseView ?

Comment: Yes, there is need to actionbarsherlock library as its used as theme in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1** download library file

http://amlcurran.github.io/ShowcaseView/

**step 2** extract file

**step 3** you will find two folders library and sample

**step 4** make new folder with new name like **showcaselib** or any name and make inside it new folder with name **src**

**step 5** goto library folder and you will find **res and AndroidManifest.xml** files
           move these files to **showcaselib folder** and move com folder (library\src\main\java) to your src folder (showcaselib\src)

**step 6** impot **showcaselib folder**

**step 7** Select **showcaselib project** and right click and Goto> Preference. -Select Android tab
and chose in project build target **Android 4.4.2**
and click in **Is library**

**step 8** goto project tab in eclipce and chose clean

**step 9** add **showcaselib** to your project by Select your project and right click and Goto> Preference. -Select Android tab and from the right side click on Add button which will show you the list of library projects where you select your **showcaselib** project and add it and Apply it.

***Update : add actionbarsherlock library ***

**step 9**
download library from here http://actionbarsherlock.com

**step 10**
after downloaded you will find **actionbarsherlock folder

**step 11** import **actionbarsherlock folder**

**step 12** Select **actionbarsherlock project** and right click and Goto> Preference. -Select Android tab
and chose in project build target **Android 4.4.2**
and click in **Is library**

**step 9** add **actionbarsherlock ** to **showcaselib** by Select your project and right click and Goto> Preference. -Select Android tab and from the right side click on Add button which will show you the list of library projects where you select **actionbarsherlock ** project and add it and Apply it.

**step 13** goto project tab in eclipce and chose clean

**step 14** do step 9

Comment: Is showcaseview then ready to use or do i need something else ?

Comment: @ent30 Yes, Actionbarsherlock library is required to add.

Comment: @GrIsHu Do i have to add Actionbarsherlock to my own Project or to ShowcaseView library ?

Comment: You have to add actionbarsherlock library into your own project.

Comment: @ent30 go back to my answer ... I updated it (add actionbarsherlock library to showcaselib )

Answer (score 0):

**To add ShowcaseView Library in your Project:**

-Extract the zip file which you have downloaded from the [Link](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

-Open Eclipse and Goto>File>Import and select option Android from popup as below:

[image]

-After that press Next>Click on Browse.. and select your Library project where you have extracted your zip file

-finish.

After successfully importing into your workspace add that library project into your application's build path as below:

-Select your project and right click and Goto> Preference.
-Select Android tab and from the right side click on Add button which will show you the list of library projects where you select your showcaselibrary project and add it and Apply it.

[image]
-Now you have successfully added showcaselibrary into your application.

Same way you can add actionbarsherlock library also. 
To get step by step details check out [Adding the library to your project](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/)

**My Project contains appcombat-v7 -libray ??? (what is it used for ?)**

-appcombat-v7-library is a support library which provides backward compatibility of some of the views which are available from the newer api levels.